# Laravel Compare Collection Objects and Display Changes

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel and Spatie's Laravel Activity Log plugin. When calling `{{$activity->changes}}`, it produces a collection with all of the `attributes`, which are the post-change columns of a database table, and an `old` set of pre-change properties.

**Example**

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "id":69,
        "first_name":"Duane",
        "last_name":"Bartell",
        "dob":"1986-06-22",
        "unique_id":"DuaneBartell1986-06-22",
        "created_at":"2018-10-23 09:56:54",
        "updated_at":"2018-10-27 08:41:24"
    },
    "old": {
        "id":69,
        "first_name":"Duane",
        "last_name":"Bartell",
        "dob":"1986-06-21",
        "unique_id":"DuaneBartell1986-06-21",
        "created_at":"2018-10-23 09:56:54",
        "updated_at":"2018-10-23 09:56:54"
    }
}
```

In this example, I changed the `dob`, which also changed the `unique_id` and updated the `updated_at` timestamp. What I'm wanting to do is display only the attributes that have changed as a changes feature.

Also please keep in mind that the properties/column names will change from model to model. Will I need to create some sort of solution for each different model, or is there something generic I can use?

**Edit**

Also, what is the best method to display this information on a blade? I was trying `{{$log->properties->attributes->id}}`, and it would not work.

**Edit 2: Additional Information**

The example above is the raw return of calling `{{$activity->changes}}` in a blade. The plugin states that calling this will return an ARRAY, like so:

```
[
   'attributes' => [
        'name' => 'original name',
        'text' => 'Lorum',
    ],
    'old' => [
        'name' => 'updated name',
        'text' => 'Lorum',
    ],
];
```

I'm trying different ways to pull this data. Using `$attributes = array_get($log->properties, 'attributes.dob');` will return the correct `dob`, but for whatever reason, I can't seem to pull the full group of `attributes` to compare with the `old`.

Answer (score 0):

**First Answer**

The example data is JSON, so it's unclear if they are arrays or objects.  In this case I'm going to build them like arrays but cast them to objects.  If these are arrays, you can get rid of the `(object)` and the `get_object_vars` calls.

Let's set up our test data:

```
$attributes = (object) [
  "id" => 69,
  "first_name" => "Duane",
  "last_name" => "Bartell",
  "dob" => "1986-06-22",
  "unique_id" => "DuaneBartell1986-06-22",
  "created_at" => "2018-10-23 09:56:54",
  "updated_at" => "2018-10-27 08:41:24"
];

$old = (object) [
  "id" => 69,
  "first_name" => "Duane",
  "last_name" => "Bartell",
  "dob" => "1986-06-21",
  "unique_id" => "DuaneBartell1986-06-21",
  "created_at" => "2018-10-23 09:56:54",
  "updated_at" => "2018-10-23 09:56:54"
];

$result = (object) [
  'attributes' => $attributes,
  'old' => $old
];
```

Now we have a `$result` object that has two properties. Each property is an object containing the keys from your example.

To find the difference, you can do this:

```
$changedFields = array_diff(
    get_object_vars($result->attributes), 
    get_object_vars($result->old)
);
```

Now `$changedFields` will contain the three properties as an array that changed.

**Second Answer**

Without knowing the exact structure of the object and the code you used to insert the data into the view, I can't tell you exactly how to access it via blade.  Remember, if it's an object, you can point to it with this `->` - but if it's an array, you have to use array syntax.

Comment: I updated the question with some information. The documentation is saying that it is an array, but I am not able to reference the attributes/old aspects.